# AWS RDS Postgres Upgrade without losing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, rds

I currently have a Postgresql v9.3.3 running on AWS RDS. I've learned that if I upgrade Postgres to 9.3.5 that I can create read replicas.

However, I am afraid of losing data. Can I just select "modify" from the console "instance actions" section and upgrade to 9.3.5 without losing any data; or do I need to do something special?

Comment: Upgrading from 9.3.3 to 9.3.5 should be a simple instance restart. It's on-disk compatible. Unless RDS does something crazy it should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fine - if there is a possible data loss AWS wouldn't provide a single click update.
As this is only a minor version update it is pretty easy to upgrade without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

What Osterjour said is only partly true. There is almost no way to lose data, especially if configured in multi-az.

1. Minor upgrades such as versions etc. will not cause downtime.
2. Adding read-replicas will not cause downtime, but I/O will be
   suspended briefly while the snapshot is being made and
   synchronized to the new read replica.
3. Modifying the instance **type** will cause downtime, even with multi-az.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid losing data you would have to come up with a data integrity validation strategy prior to upgrade and post upgrade even if is minor upgrade.

**From experience=** i migrated postgreSQL 9.6.6 to 9.6.9 (minor upgrade). Small validation and the downtime was 12 minutes due to manual snapshot and automatic pre-upgrade and post-upgrade performed by AWS RDS. In general terms it was good and everything was smooth.

**Recommendation=** test. Do dry-runs many. and pay attention to the DB load plus the DB extensions.

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html
```

Check AWS official Doc. [AWS RDS Upgrades](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html)

Please Let us know after 4 years what you decided and how did it go?

Comment: If you do a manual snapshot not long before an upgrade it can reduce the work required for any automatic snapshots taken during the upgrade. This is because snapshots are incremental.